# dynamic row should contain different (dynamic) components in PrimeFaces datatable

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

I want to create a datatable in jsf using primefaces where I have to add rows dynamically. But each row added dynamically should have different components. For example if first row is added then it should contain inputtext component in all columns. For second row it should contain SelectOnemenu in its first column and input text for other columns. Similarly third row should contain outputtext in first column and inputtext in other columns.

Comment: if your problem got solved? Respond or accept the answer so that it would be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the `rendered` attribute. E.g.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.fields}" var="field">
    <h:column>
        <h:inputText value="#{field.value}" rendered="#{field.type == 'TEXT'}" />
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{field.value}" rendered="#{field.type == 'MENU'}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{field.availableValues}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:outputText value="#{field.value}" rendered="#{field.type == 'OUTPUT'}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```